# Compile Emacs with xwidgets in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: compilation, emacs-internals

Going to build Emacs from the [git repository](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs).
Found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1128721/compiling-emacs-25-1-on-ubuntu-16-04) and [this](https://www.debyum.com/install-emacs-in-ubuntu/) resources that suggest to compile it with xwidgets for Ubuntu 16.04.

On my Ubuntu 14.04, did install the corresponding dependencies with `apt-get`, but still getting this `configure` error:

```
configure: error: xwidgets requested but WebKitGTK+ not found.
```

Though `libgtk-3-dev` and `libwebkitgtk-3.0-dev` are installed.
Any hints?

Comment: Reading this: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2w8z1s/has_anyone_managed_to_get_the_xwidgets_branch/ , I will probably regret from using xwidgets...

Answer (score 9):

For emacs-26 on ubuntu, the required package for `--with-xwidgets` is `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev`.

Found in comment [here](https://superuser.com/a/1129052/934964), confirmed by experience.

Answer (score 3):

Emacs switched from webkit1gtk to webkit2gtk so you'll need to install that instead.  Your GTK package should be fine.

PS: I agree with the linked article, although I wouldn't put it this drastically.  You're better off with using a dedicated browser built upon WebKit or WebEngine.  If all you're after is Emacs keybindings, EXWM might be an alternative.